# How to make a script "wait" for an operation to finish?

Tags: software-installation, expect, oracle

I have two scripts, or maybe better call one a wrapper for the another.

Here comes the wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "./installOracleDatabase.sh"

expect "replace Disk1/upgrade/gen_inst.sql?" { send "N\r" }
expect "Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express" { send "\r" }
expect "Specify a port that will be used for the database listener" { send "\r" }
expect "initial configuration:" { send "root\r" }
expect "Confirm the password:" { send "root\r" }
expect "Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot" { send "y\r" }
```

And here is the main script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#install required libraries and programs
sudo yum -y install libaio bc flex unzip
#unzipping the Oracle package
unzip -q oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
cd Disk1
sudo rpm -ivh oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

cat " . /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

The problem with the second script is, that after the last step in `sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure`, when the configuring script is asking "Do you want Oracle (...) to be started on boot", right after that step, during the normal installation, Oracle is doing some other steps:

```
Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...Done
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
Installation completed successfully.
```

This step is taking some time. But my script is exiting right after answering `y` to the last question...

How can I force the script to wait for the whole configuration to finish?

Comment: `cat " . /u01/app/oracle....` is probably not what you want; maybe `echo ". /u01/app....`

Comment: change your `timeout` value to `-1`

Answer (score 0):

In order to cause the `expect` script to wait until Oracle last step, you can try adding the following line to the end of the `expect` script

```
expect "Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done" { send "\r" }
expect "Configuring database...Done" { send "\r" }
expect "Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done" { send "\r" }
expect "Installation completed successfully." { send "\r" }
expect eof
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work... It seems to wait a little longer, but it doesnt reach "Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
Installation completed successfully."

Comment: @ZibiSmough - updated my answer. what happened when you provide the entire output as `expected output`?